# How to minimize taxes for a university lecturer?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

I am a Green Card holder and work as a lecturer in a university at Massachusetts with income of about 15K. How can I prepare tax filings to minimize tax payments?

Comment: Was your income reported on a W-2 or 1099? Did you incur any expenses related to your lecturing that were not reimbursed?

Comment: @HartCO Don't employee unreimbursed expenses come under the category of Miscellaneous Expenses subject to a 2% floor which entire category was eliminated by the recent Tax Cuts for the Rich and Wealthy Act of December 2017?

Comment: @DilipSarwate That's why it matters how OP's income is reported.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything unusual about your situation.

If you weren't a permanent resident, you could look into using tax treaties, but you are, and so you can't use them.

You must pay taxes just like the citizens.

You probably want to file 1040EZ and whatever state and local tax forms are appropriate.